# Is it possible to debug NativeActivity based application?

Tags: android, android-ndk

To debug native code in android application using gdb, first i need to start my sdk based application and stop it at breakpoint right before loading the library with native code, after that I need to start gdb, and so on... But how about NativeActivity based application which have no any java code and library loading point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DS-5 debugger](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/) for that. I use it for a long time and it works OK.

Comment: is it possible to use DS-5 debugger to debug linux kernel on my board? say...set breakpoints on the kernel's scheduler?